# Minimum RBAC permission needed to view all Azure Container Groups within the Resource Group?

Tags: azure-active-directory, containers, rbac, azure-container-instances, azure-rbac

My logic app creates new container groups within same Resource Group. I have contributor RBAC role on logic app, but I don't have any RBAC role at Resource Group level. What RBAC role should I ask so that I can view all Azure Container Groups that get created by logic app in resource group? or do I need to define any custom role?
We follow least permission model, so I will not get straight away 'Reader' / 'Contributor' role on Resource group for this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like operations are directly not available in built-in RBAC permissions .You may have to create custom role for the required operations .

- To create a custom role, check out the actions that are available to define your permissions for the container groups and create custom role [***from scratch***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-portal#start-from-scratch).

[image]

Create a JSON file with actions and not actions declared.
[***Azure resource provider operations | Microsoft Learn***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftcontainerinstance)

***JSON:***

```
{
   "assignableScopes": [
     "/subscriptions/<this is optional : you may limit the visibility to one or more subscriptions>"
   ],
   "description": "Get all the Container groups",
   "Name": "Read",
   "permissions": [
     {
       "actions": [
         "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/read",
         "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroupProfiles/read",
         ...
         
       ],
       "dataActions": [],
       "notActions": [],
       "notDataActions": []
     }
   ],
   "roleType": "CustomRole"
 }
```

---

[image]

---

**Reference:** [Create or update Azure custom roles using the Azure portal - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-portal)